# PHP Curl POSTVARS with '&' in it

Tags: php, curl

```
define('POSTURL', 'http://xxx.info/includes/process.php?action=update');
define('POSTVARS', 'u=google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=love');  // POST VARIABLES TO BE SENT

 $ch = curl_init(POSTURL);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST      ,1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS    ,POSTVARS);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  ,1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER      ,0);  // DO NOT RETURN HTTP HEADERS
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  ,1);  // RETURN THE CONTENTS OF THE CALL
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "yourcookiefile.txt");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "yourcookiefile.txt");
 $Rec_Data = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
echo $Rec_Data;
```

I am trying to pass '*google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=love*'.

My problem is that `POSTVARS` is taking *google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar* as 1st field and *&q=love* as 2nd, but this is one value not 2.

How can I pass POSTVARS with '&' in it?

Thx

Comment: shouldn't the postvars be only `output=toolbar&q=love`

Comment: @RoyalBg i am trying to post 'google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=love' to one of the proxy site ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should `urlecode()` it before sending

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`http_build_query()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).